# Use pdfinterwordspaceon with pdflatex from MiKTeX on Windows

Tags: fonts, errors, pdftex, miktex

In [Text copied from pdf is missing spaces with newtxtext](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317586/), I have found out that I want to use `\pdfinterwordspaceon`, which is available as of TeX Live 2014, for example. I, however, am using MiKTeX (with `pdflatex`, on Windows)

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.6.30)  7 JUL 2016 11:33
```

and the following MWE does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfinterwordspaceon
\begin{document}
    Compile!
\end{document}
```

These are the error messages that I get:

```
line 5: Font \csname\endcsname=dummy-space at 1.00375pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \end{document}
line 5: Font \csname\endcsname=dummy-space at 1.00375pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \end{document}
```

In addition, I have looked at a couple of log files:

```
miktex-maketfm.log
2016-07-07 11:25:05,150-0400 INFO  makex - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
2016-07-07 11:25:05,385-0400 INFO  makex - Running hbf2gf.exe...
2016-07-07 11:25:05,577-0400 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font dummy-space.

miktex-makemf.log
2016-07-07 11:25:05,338-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - The dummy-space source file could not be found.
2016-07-07 11:25:06,240-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - The dummy-space source file could not be found.
2016-07-07 11:25:07,216-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - The dummy-space source file could not be found.
2016-07-07 11:25:08,103-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - The dummy-space source file could not be found.
2016-07-07 11:25:09,014-0400 FATAL miktex-makemf - The dummy-space source file could not be found.

miktex-makepk.log
2016-07-07 11:25:09,531-0400 FATAL miktex-makepk - Unknown command-line option.
```

I have also tried this, with the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfmapline{+dummy-space <dummy-space.pfb}
\pdfinterwordspaceon
\begin{document}
    Compile!
\end{document}
```

Should this work? Do I need additional packages? And if yes, which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out that downloading `dummy-space.pfb` and `dummy-space.tfm` from [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/doc/pdftex/tests/01-fake-interword-space) and storing them next to my `tex` file makes my second MWE compile successfully. The line

```
\pdfmapline{+dummy-space <dummy-space.pfb}
```

seems to be required -- it does not compile without it.

Of course, I would be interested in a more automated solution available through the MiKTeX package manager.

Comment: Make a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/. In texlive the font is stored in /fonts/type1/public/pdftex/dummy-space.pfb

Comment: Done: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2513/

Comment: Looks like that was their old repo. I reported it at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/223